# GA - set up statistics for subdomain only

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

The problem is - i need to track subdomain separately. and thus i've created  separate  tracker on subdomain.doman.com. but google analytics offers this code

```
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

And it doesn't work when i place it in subdomain.domain.com ...
Should i change  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'domain.com']); line to
`_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'subdomaindomain.com']);`
I plan to track only that subdomain. Could you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm, a similar setup is working on my end.

Alternatively you can just create a new profile within your existing web property and set an include to match just that hostname.

Another solution is to use Google tag manager to deploy a given GA snippet on a specific hostname via the firing rules.

Comment: With Google Tag Manager you create a new container and place the code snippet right after the opening of the <body> tag.

Then you create new snippets (for instance, one that you want for this particular subdomain). Then create a new firing rule for that tag to go off when the URL includes the hostname. Create a new version to deploy. To check whether the tag is being included in through the container, you can check the DOM via developer tools in Chrome/Firefox